# tengo un buscador el cual me toma registros repetidos, como hago para solucionarlo?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo dos tablas es mi BD una llamada publicacion y la otra publicaciondet.
la tabla publicacion tiene los siguientes campos

```
1   codPublicacion  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  
2   tipoPublicacion char(1) 
3   desPublicacion  varchar(100)
4   ubiPublicacion  varchar(25) 
6   nomPublicacion  varchar(20)
7   fecPublicacion  datetime
```

y la tabla publicaciondet

```
1   codPubDetPrimaria   int(11)
3   codPublicacion  int(11) foreing key
4   arcPubDet   varchar(100)
```

en el campo arcPubDet se guarda el nombre de las imágenes por registro, (por cada registro se guardan 4 fotos) para mostrar.

el problema es que cuando hago una consulta buscando cualquier palabra ingresada en el buscador, cuando la encuentra me muestra los 4 registros y no solo uno de los 4.

```
    $buscar = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT pub.codPublicacion, pub.tipoPublicacion,
    pub.fecPublicacion, pub.nomPublicacion, pubd.arcPubDet, pub.fecPublicacion, 
    SUBSTRING(pub.desPublicacion, 1, 50) AS mini  FROM publicacion AS pub   
    INNER JOIN publicaciondet AS pubd ON pub.codPublicacion = pubd.codPublicacion WHERE 
    pub.nomPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR
    pub.desPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR        
    pub.ubiPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR
    pub.fecPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' AND 
    pubd.arcPubDet LIKE 'f1%'
    ORDER BY pub.fecPublicacion DESC");
```

y con el ultimo    LIKE     lo que hago es definir que solo me traiga el nombre de la imagen que comience con "f1", la cual es la imagen principal pero aun asi me trae los 4 registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero su ayuda gracias!

Comment: Puedes intentar con simplemente agregar DISTINCT: `SELECT DISTINCT pub.codPublicacion, ..` (al referencial el detalle, se repetira tantas veces como calce con la busqueda)

Comment: el problema es que para codPublicacion en tabla 1 tenes varias entradas con igual  codPublicacion en la otra tabla.  es decir tenes 4 registros con igual codPublicacion en tabla 2. debes buscar unico valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes incluir `DISTINCT` para asegurar que no hayan resultados repetidos (debido al detalle).

Ademas, para que la condiciones AND funcionen en conjunto con las OR, estas ultimas deben estar separadas del resto por paréntesis (solucionando esto adecuadamente, puede que nos ea necesario `DISTINCT`)

```
$buscar = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT DISTINCT pub.codPublicacion, pub.tipoPublicacion,
pub.fecPublicacion, pub.nomPublicacion, pubd.arcPubDet, pub.fecPublicacion, 
SUBSTRING(pub.desPublicacion, 1, 50) AS mini  FROM publicacion AS pub   
INNER JOIN publicaciondet AS pubd ON pub.codPublicacion = pubd.codPublicacion WHERE 
(pub.nomPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR
 pub.desPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR        
 pub.ubiPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR
 pub.fecPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%') 
AND pubd.arcPubDet LIKE 'f1%'
ORDER BY pub.fecPublicacion DESC");
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me faltaban los paréntesis ahora ya me hace bien la consulta :D

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema esta cuando usas el or, ya que existe precedencia como en la suma y la multiplicación, para que no importa las condiciones or siempre te de el que comienza f1, agrupa de la siguiente forma.

```
$buscar = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT pub.codPublicacion, pub.tipoPublicacion,
pub.fecPublicacion, pub.nomPublicacion, pubd.arcPubDet, pub.fecPublicacion, 
SUBSTRING(pub.desPublicacion, 1, 50) AS mini  FROM publicacion AS pub   
INNER JOIN publicaciondet AS pubd ON pub.codPublicacion = pubd.codPublicacion WHERE 
(
  pub.nomPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR
  pub.desPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR        
  pub.ubiPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' OR
  pub.fecPublicacion LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' 
)
AND 
pubd.arcPubDet LIKE 'f1%'
ORDER BY pub.fecPublicacion DESC");
```

Comment: Gracias ya logre solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar `limit 1` a la consulta... `distinct` también se podría usar, pero implica más trabajo *de CPU* que lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias ya logre solucionarlo